# Unix File listing with date as prefix in names

Tags: linux

How can I list files based on names with date prefix & suffix. Ex: I have file with name as "**http_access_2017-04-13.log**" then how can I with files with last five days back files ??

Answer (score 2):

Create you time stamps with `date -d`:

```
ago ()
{
  date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$1 days ago"
}

for n in $(seq 5); do
  echo http_access_$(ago $n).log
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
ls -lr http_access*.log | tail -5
```